# iPhone App Internal "Settings"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

I want to keep track of several different things between launches like settings, integers, etc. I'm not sure if Core Data is what I need for this because I don't need to set a value for an entity multiple times, display in a list view, etc. What should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Looking into this now. Am I able to change the settings within the application at runtime and save them?

Comment: @James Martinez Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `NSUserDefaults`.